# How to dynamically create xtype templates in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

So I have a view, and a controller linked to that view, and I would like to dynamically assign values to a xtype item in the view via store.

So for example, I would like dynamically setup `layouts` (please have a look at the proveded code) and `urls`

```
    items: [
        {
            itemId: 'nav_home',
            id: 'homeView',
            layout: "{layout}",
            items: [{
              xtype: 'articlelist',
              id: 'latestNews',
              url: {url},
            }
        ],
    },
```

Could anyone lead me how to approach this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use initialize function to render components based on some condition. Here is an example :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias : 'widget.myview',
    config: {
        items   : [],
        mylayout: null
    },
    initialize : function(){
        var me = this;
        if(me.config.mylayout == 'horizontal'){
            me.add({
                xtype   : 'panel',
                layout  : 'hbox',
                items   : [{
                    xtype   : 'panel',
                    html    : 'first content'
                },
                {
                    xtype   : 'panel',
                    html    : 'second content'
                }]
            });
        } else if(me.config.mylayout == 'vertical'){
            me.add({
                xtype   : 'panel',
                layout  : 'vbox',
                items   : [{
                    xtype   : 'panel',
                    html    : 'first content'
                },
                {
                    xtype   : 'panel',
                    html    : 'second content'
                },
                {
                    xtype   : 'panel',
                    html    : 'third content'
                }]
            });
        }
        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

You can create this view like this:

```
var myView = Ext.create("MyApp.view.MyView", {
    mylayout : 'vertical'
});
```

`mylayout` could be any configuration object you want to pass.

Comment: However, I just figured out, that there our view extends: `Ext.ux.slidenavigation.View`

And it throws a bug: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined`, I believe it's because there is nothing in `this.config.items`

Comment: Hey bud, check this question, I believe you should know the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644890/dynamically-add-xtype-items-to-the-panel-with-slidenavigatoin