# Dynamically add xtype items to the panel with slidenavigatoin

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

So I'm trying to put items dynamically to the panel that has `slidenavigation` feature:

```
// FlyoutNavigation.js 
Ext.define("APN.view.FlyoutNavigation", {
    id: "flyoutNavigationPanel",
    extend: 'Ext.ux.slidenavigation.View',
```

Here is the initialisation of the `view` in another view:

```
        // MainViewContainer.js 
        this.home = "Some var"
        this.flyout = Ext.create('APN.view.FlyoutNavigation', {
            id: 'flyoutNavigationPanel',
            home: this.home
        });
```

Than I'm trying to use this variable in the `this.config.items` section, however that doesn't work, it seems that Sencha compiles everything first and than initialiases the components, I might be wrong, I'm really new to Sencha Framework.

So here is the view where the `home` variable is used:

```
Ext.define("APN.view.FlyoutNavigation", {
    id: "flyoutNavigationPanel",
    extend: 'Ext.ux.slidenavigation.View',
    xtype: 'flyoutnavigation',
    requires: [
... heaps of things omitted ...
    ],
    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent();  
        this.setupDynamicItems();
    },
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                itemId: 'nav_home',
                id: 'homeView',
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'articlelist',
                        id: 'latestNews',
                        feedUrlName: this.home, // - that's the place where UNDEFINED occurs
                        flex: 1
                    }
                ],
            },
```

So `this.home` is undefined...

**One possible solution**
Comming from this question: [How to dynamically create xtype templates in Sencha Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622319/how-to-dynamically-create-xtype-templates-in-sencha-touch)

I decided to put all the code in `this.config.items.add({ ... my items ... })` however `Ext.ux.slidenavigation.View` looks like gave me the BUG! :( as the initialise method occurs after the binding methods on items of `FlyoutNavigation` view.

Here is the message from of the bug: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined View.js:310` which is basically this line: `if (Ext.isFunction(item.raw.handler)) {`

So my questions would be

1. How to get the instance variable in the config.items section? If that's possible, than all is OK
2. Or do you know the work around of this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use `this.config` when defining the class, instead you can use initialize function as I told you earlier. So you should be able to do this:

```
initialize : function() {
    var me = this;
    var home = me.config.home;
    me.add({
        itemId: 'nav_home',
        id: 'homeView',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'articlelist',
                id: 'latestNews',
                feedUrlName: home,
                flex: 1
            }
        ],
    });
}
```

OR if you have defined `homeView` in parent class, you can do this:

```
initialize : function() {
    var me = this;
    var home = me.config.home;
    me.down('#homeView').add({
        xtype: 'articlelist',
        id: 'latestNews',
        feedUrlName: home,
        flex: 1
    });
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getDocked'` 

Seems like `items: []` returns this issue

Comment: From what I see, items have to be declared before initialisation

Comment: I moved stuff to initialise, still dunno what's the issue with `getDocked`

Comment: And there is another question I believe you should be familiar with :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661061/how-to-manipulate-dynamic-objects-in-sencha-touch

Comment: @DanMyasnikov my email id is there in profile, you can use it to contact me for future deals ;-)

Comment: Do you want to check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142028/how-to-add-tap-event-to-youtube-iframe