# How to manipulate dynamic objects in Sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

So I would like to dynamically load / change elements of the `xtype objects`. So for example on the logic in the initialise method I would like to load either one or the other `this.down("#homeView").title`.

```
Ext.define("APN.view.FlyoutNavigation", {
    id: "flyoutNavigationPanel",
    extend: 'Ext.ux.slidenavigation.View',
    requires: [
        'Ext.Container',
    ],
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                itemId: 'nav_home',
                id: 'homeView',
                title: "theTitleThatIwantToChange"
...
```

While I'm looking at things like `setHtml`, or just simply assigning this variable to `""` doesn't have any impact on the UI component.

So my question is how to dynamically load the variable of an object `this.down("#homeView")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the title you need to call `setTitle()` method. Can you provide a code where you try to set it?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, that did work.

Do you want to check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142028/how-to-add-tap-event-to-youtube-iframe